# Intuitive proof that $U(n)$ isn't isomorphic to $SU(n) \times S^1$

Tags: group-theory, intuition

One way to prove this is by comparing their centers. However, I do not feel that this proof gives me much insight into the structures of the groups. (It would make me very happy if I were to be corrected though!)

Is there a more intuitive proof? My intuition is that the second group is "larger", but I haven't been able to turn this into a proof.

Comment: Well, the two groups have the same dimension, so it's unclear what you mean by "larger" here.

Comment: The "larger" was because there are multiple obvious copies of $U(n)$ in $SU(n) \times S^1$. I haven't been able to get anywhere with that intuition though, so it may well be that there isn't any useful sense in which the second group is larger.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$n \ge 2$ throughout. Taking determinants gives a short exact sequence

$$1 \to SU(n) \to U(n) \xrightarrow{\det} U(1) \to 1$$

and what you'd really like is for an isomorphism $U(n) \cong SU(n) \times U(1)$ to respect the structure of this short exact sequence. (If there were some random isomorphism that didn't have this property that would be less interesting.)

For starters, this requires that $det : U(n) \to U(1)$ have a [section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_(category_theory)), or equivalently that the short exact sequence above splits, which it does: for example, we can send $z \in U(1)$ to the diagonal matrix with entries $z, 1, 1, \dots$. This section allows us to write $U(n)$ as a semidirect product

$$U(n) \cong SU(n) \rtimes U(1)$$

and this cannot be improved to a direct product. This is possible if and only if it is possible to choose a section of $\det : U(n) \to U(1)$ whose image is central. Now, the center of $U(n)$ is the diagonal copy of $U(1)$. When restricted to the center, the determinant map is the map

$$U(1) \ni z \mapsto z^n \in U(1)$$

and this map doesn't have a section for the same reason that $\sqrt[n]{z}$ is not a holomorphic function of $z$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sort of addendum to Qiaochu's answer, the purpose of which is to tie up the loose end it leaves in the sense that it only considers isomorphisms compatible with the short exact sequence associated to the surjective $\det\colon \mathrm{U}(n) \to S^1$.

**Claim**: Any group homorphism $\psi\colon \mathrm{SU}(n)\times S^1\to \mathrm{U}(n)$ must form part of a commutative diagram

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
1 @>>> \mathrm{SU}(n)@>{\iota_1}>>  \mathrm{SU}(n)\times S^1 @>{\pi_2}>> S^1 @>>> 1\\
& @V{\theta}VV @V{\psi}VV @V{\bar{\psi}}VV\\
1 @>>> \mathrm{SU}(n) @>>> \mathrm{U}(n) @>{\det}>> S^1 @>>> 1
\end{CD}$$
where $\theta \colon \mathrm{SU}(n) \to \mathrm{SU}(n)$ and $\bar{\psi}\colon S^1 \to S^1$ are group homomorphisms, and $\iota_1(s) = (s,1)$, $\pi_2(s,t)=t$.

To show this we need the following definition and lemma:

**Definition**: If $G$ is a group then $G'\leq G$, the *derived subgroup* of $G$ is the subgroup generated by $\{g_1g_2g_1^{-1}g_2^{-1}: g_1,g_2 \in G\}$. It is a normal subgroup, and if $q\colon G \to  G/G'$ is the corresponding quotient map then $G/G'$ is abelian and moreover if $\theta\colon G \to H$ is a group homomorphism from $G$ to an abelian group $H$, then $\theta$ factors through $q$, that is, $G'\subseteq \ker(\theta)$ and hence $\theta$ induces a homomorphism $\bar{\theta}\colon G/G' \to H$ such that $\theta = \bar{\theta}\circ q$.

Note that it follows immediately from the definition that if $\eta \colon G \to H$ is any group homomorphism then $\eta(G') = \eta(G)'\subseteq H'$. The following Lemma is standard, but we include a proof at the end of this answer for the sake of completeness.

**Lemma**: For any $n>1$, $\mathrm{U}(n)' = \mathrm{SU}(n)$ and $\mathrm{SU}(n)' = \mathrm{SU}(n)$.

**Proof of claim**:
Note first that by the Lemma we have
$$
(\mathrm{SU}(n)\times S^1)' = \mathrm{SU}(n)'\times (S^1)'= \mathrm{SU}(n)\times \{1\} = \ker(\pi_2)
$$
Now $\det\circ \psi\colon \mathrm{SU}(n)\times S^1\to S^1$ and $S^1$ is abelian, it follows that $\ker(\pi_2)\subseteq \ker(\det\circ \psi)$, and hence there is a unique homomorphism $\bar{\psi}\colon S^1 \to S^1$ such that $\det\circ \psi = \bar{\psi}\circ \pi_2$. Moreover, since $\mathrm{SU}(n)\times \{1\}$ is the derived subgroup of $\mathrm{SU}(n)\times S^1$, its image under $\psi$ must lie in $\mathrm{U}(n)' = \mathrm{SU}(n)$, and hence $\psi_{|\mathrm{SU}(n)}$ induces a homomorphism $\theta\colon \mathrm{SU}(n) \to \mathrm{SU}(n)$, establishing the required commutative diagram.

Now suppose that $\psi\colon \mathrm{SU}(n)\times S^1 \to \mathrm{U}(n)$ is an isomorphism. Then $\theta$ and $\bar{\psi}$ must be isomorphisms, and hence replacing $\psi$ with $(\theta^{-1}\times \bar{\psi}^{-1})\circ \psi$ we may assume that $\theta=\text{id}_{\mathrm{SU}(n)}$ and $\bar{\psi} = \text{id}_{S^1}$.

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathrm{SU}(n) @<{\pi_1}<< \mathrm{SU}(n)\times S^1 @>{\pi_2}>> S^1 \\
@| @V{\psi}VV  @|\\
\mathrm{SU}(n) @>>> \mathrm{U}(n) @>{\det}>> S^1
\end{CD}$$

It follows that $\nu(t)= \psi(1,t)$ is a homomorphism $\nu\colon S^1 \to \mathrm{U}(n)$ satisfying $\nu(t)g= g\nu(t)$ for all $g \in \mathrm{U}(n)$  (since $(1,t)\in Z(\mathrm{SU}(n)\times S^1)$) and $\det(\nu(t))= t$. Since $Z(\mathrm{U}(n)) = S^1.I_n$ it follows that $\nu(t) = \lambda(t).I_n$ for a unique homomorphism $\lambda \colon S^1 \to S^1$.

But now the restriction of $\det$ to $S^1.I_n$ is just the homomorphism $m_n\colon S^1 \to S^1$ given by $m_n(t)=t^n$, and for any homomorphism $\eta \colon S^1 \to S^1$ we have $m_n \circ \eta = \eta \circ m_n$, hence if there exists $\lambda \colon S^1 \to S^1$ satisfying $t= \det(\lambda(t).I_n)$ then  $m_n\circ \lambda = \lambda \circ m_n = \text{id}_{S^1}$, so that $\lambda$ and $m_n$ must therefore be isomorphisms, which is impossible since $\ker(m_n) = \{t \in S^1: t^n=1\} \neq \{1\}$.

**Proof of Lemma**: Since any commutator has determinant $1$, the derived subgroup of $\mathrm{U}(n)$ is certainly contained in $\mathrm{SU}(n)$, thus it suffices to show that $\mathrm{SU}(n)$ is perfect, that is, $\mathrm{SU}(n)' = \mathrm{SU}(n)$. In fact, any element of $\mathrm{SU}(n)$ is equal to a commutator in $\mathrm{SU}(n)$. To see this, note that any unitary transformation is diagonalizable, so we may assume
$$
g \in \mathrm{SU}(n) = \text{diag}(e^{i\theta_1},\ldots,e^{i\theta_n}), \textit{ where } \sum_{i=1}^n \theta_j \in 2 \pi i\mathbb Z.
$$
Now let $P_n$ be the matrix with entries $(P_n)_{ij} = (-1)^{(n-1)\delta_{i,n}}\delta_{\overline{i+1},\bar{j}}$ where for $m\in \mathbb Z$, $\overline{m}\in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and $m-\overline{m} \in n\mathbb Z$).  Thus $P_n$ cycles the standard basis vectors, sending $e_i\mapsto e_{i+1}$ for $1\leq i \leq n-1$ and $e_n \mapsto (-1)^{(n-1)} e_1$, where the sign ensures that $\det(P_n)=1$. Then if $h = \text{diag}(e^{ia_1},\ldots,e^{ia_n})$, we have
$$
hP_nh^{-1}P_n^{-1} = \text{diag}(e^{i(a_1-a_2)},\ldots, e^{i(a_n-a_1)})
$$
so that if we set $a_i = t+\sum_{j=i}^n \theta_j$, where $t$ is chosen so that $h \in \mathrm{SU}(n)$, then since $-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \theta_n \in \theta_1 +2\pi\mathbb Z$ it follows that $hw_nh^{-1}w_n^{-1}=g$.